# Can the order of the display properties of an Azure Custom Event be controlled?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, custom-events

I have created an Azure Custom Event using the Azure Telemetry Client which takes the 1st parameter as the name of the CustomEvent and the 2nd parameter as a String Dictionary. A very brief description would be as follows although I'm using C# and not JS:

```
TelemetryClient.TrackEvent({
  name: 'Custom Event Name',
  properties: {
  'Additional Info': 'N/A',
  'First Name': 'Johnny',
  'Last Name': 'AppleSeed',
  'User Name': 'JSeed12',
  }
});
```

When the Custom Event displays in Azure the order I've given to the properties appears to be randomly set and different from the way I provided them in the string Dictionary.

The business would like to have the properties displayed in a specific order and so I was wondering if there is any way to manipulate it or is this just something that we have no control over?

Here is an Azure screenshot of what I'm referring to:

[image]

Comment: What view is the business looking at? Do they look at a specific page in the azure portal? A good way to modify / create custom views is to create workbooks or power bi reports.

Comment: Yes, they want to look at a specific page in the Azure Portal. I just added a screenshot of the area. You'll Note that the Custom Properties are unordered. But when I created the string dictionary of those properties, they were added in alphabetical order.

Comment: I would personally create a [workbook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/visualize/workbooks-overview) and give the business access to that workbook. Than you can create your own views, and have control over what is shown and how it is shown.

Comment: Thank you Peter. I will propose this as an alternative to the business.